# Cefsharp to enter data to form

Tags: javascript, chromium, cefsharp

I need Cefsharp to do a small bit of automation. What I want to do is enter data into two textfield and then press a button. To do this I'm using javascript.

```
       browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('_fcn8k');");
       browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("elems[0].click();");
       Thread.Sleep(5000);
       browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("var elems2 = document.getElementsByClassName('_kp5f7');");
       browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("var elems3 = document.getElementsByClassName('_taytv');");
       browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("elems2[0].value='" + userName + "';");
       browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("elems2[1].value='" + userPassword + "';");
       browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("elems[3].click();");
```

The code works, except for the fact that when I click the button the textfields are emptied and I get an error saying the data is wrong (since the fields are empty).

If I do it manually the data remains when the button is pressed. I really don't get why it disappears when I try to do this programmaticly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wrap all your code in an anonymous closure and execute it in one block, calling execute so many times is expensive. If you don't know what an anonymous closure is google it. Could be the website validation that's getting in the way. Open the `DevTools` and have a look (again, google if you don't know how to do this).

Comment: Thank you for the answear. It sounds like a good idea, but none the less better working :). I tried this and that should be right. getting the same result when pasting it into Chromes console - (function() { var elems2 = document.getElementsByClassName('_kp5f7'); var elems3 = document.getElementsByClassName('_taytv'); elems2[0].value='" + userName + "'; elems2[1].value='" + userPassword + "'; elems3[0].click(); })()

Comment: Once you get it working in `Chrome` it should work in `CefSharp`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it. It's the website(Instagram) that has some way of detecting it I guess. It works just fine with other sites.